# Relation between softmax and max

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

For two vectors $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbf{R}^n$, does the inequality below hold?

$\left| \text{softmax} X - \text{softmax} Y \right|
\leq
\text{max} | X - Y |$

Softmax is the same as log-sum-exp:

$\text{softmax} X
=
\log
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^n
\exp(X_i)
\right)$.

Comment: Is $\max|X-Y|$ just the maximum element of $X_Y=(|x_1-y_1|,\dots,|x_n-y_n|
)$?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  It is just the maximum element of the vector $|X-Y| = (|x_1-y_1|,...|x_n-y_n|)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Observe the following properties of $\operatorname{softmax}$:

1. $\operatorname{softmax}$ is monotone: if $X\le Y$ elementwise, then $\operatorname{softmax} X\le \operatorname{softmax} Y$.
2. If $Y$ is a constant vector $(c,\dots,c)$, then $\operatorname{softmax}(X+Y) = \operatorname{softmax}X +c$. Indeed, $e^c$ factors out of the sum, and contributes $c$ to logarithm.

In your setting, let $Z=(c,\dots,c)$ where $c=\max |X-Y|$. Since $X\le Y+Z$, we have $$\operatorname{softmax} X \le \operatorname{softmax} (Y+Z) = \operatorname{softmax} Y +c$$
Exchanging $X$ and $Y$, conclude with $|\operatorname{softmax} X - \operatorname{softmax} Y|\le c$.